# What is the correct way to write out species names in a scientific paper?

Tags: grammar, science, taxonomy

For example, in the phrase

"The study organisms were adult rove beetle *Atheta coriaria* and adult ladybird *Adalia bipunctata*"

Would it be correct to write

"The study organisms were the adult rove beetle *Atheta coriaria* and the adult ladybird *Adalia bipuntata*",

"The study organisms were adult rove beetles *Atheta coriaria* and adult ladybirds *Adalia bipuntata*",

"The study organisms were adult rove beetle *Atheta coriaria* and adult ladybird *Adalia bipuntata*",

"The study organisms were adult rove beetles (*Atheta coriaria*) and adult ladybirds (*Adalia bipuntata*)",

Or something else?

I'm in the UK, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In my technical editing experience, choice (1) ("The study organisms were the adult rove beetle *Atheta coriaria* and the adult ladybird *Adalia bipuntata*.") would be preferred. Here, the common and scientific species names are placed in [apposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apposition) (specifically, restricted apposition). Articles are correctly incorporated (in contrast to choice (3)). There seems to be no possibility for confusion.

Choice (4) ("The study organisms were adult rove beetles (*Atheta coriaria*) and adult ladybirds (*Adalia bipuntata*).") would also be acceptable. Choice (2) sounds somewhat awkward because nouns in apposition are frequently either both singular or both plural.